# Debian 10 apt update issue

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I have just done a clean installation of Debian buster, and I'm having trouble with APT.

I run `sudo apt update` and I get this

```
Ign:1 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 10.1.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20190908-01:07] buster InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 10.1.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20190908-01:07] buster Release
 Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease              
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/updates InRelease      
Hit:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Err:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.132.204 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 10.1.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20190908-01:07] buster Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:4
```

Here you have the content of my sources.list

```
    # 

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.1.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20190908-01:07]/ buster main
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.1.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20190908-01:07]/ buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster/updates main

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

I really can't understand what's the problem here, if these are the default sources that came with my clean installation inside the file, I changed nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment your `deb cdrom:` lines and comment / remove the lines

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster/updates main
```

and replace them with

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
```

I don't know if these repositories were changed, but these are (working) repos taken from the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list).

Or copy & paste an [example source.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list) from the wiki, here is the one with the additional `contrib` and `non-free` repos

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

and run `sudo apt update` again.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem upgrading [Debian 9 Stretch to Debian 10 Buster](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-debian-9-stretch-to-debian-10-buster), my issue was a **backport duplication error**:

[image: Debian 10 Backport Duplication Error]

### To Solve:

- Find the duplicated line with `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list`
  (Substituting "buster-backports.list" with "YOUR-DOUBLY-CONFIGURED-FILENAME")
- Open sources.list with `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` , find the duplicate line and comment it out with `#`
- Save file and update system with `sudo apt update`

Should be good to go. This [Linux Mint Forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=275588) helped me find my answer, might help you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Similar error, i386, Debian-10-server, without desktop env. I had a similar install on another machine with a desktop env without the problem. I simply edited /etc/apt/sources.list to match the working system.

```
root@svr2:/etc/apt# cat sources.list
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.5.0 _Buster_ - Official i386 NETINST 20200801-13:11]/ buster main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.5.0 _Buster_ - Official i386 NETINST 20200801-13:11]/ buster main

deb http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/debian/ buster main
deb-src http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/debian/ buster main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/debian/ buster-updates main
deb-src http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/debian/ buster-updates main
root@svr2:/etc/apt# apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Hit:2 http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/debian buster InRelease
Get:3 http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/debian buster-updates InRelease [51.9 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Sources [152 kB]
Fetched 269 kB in 2s (177 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```